# Java EE Subclassing LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I'm trying to subclass `LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean` in order to override the `invoke` method.

There is a client side accessing services via http invoker mechanism, and i need to unwrap all EJBExceptions because the client doesn't have the class.
I've unsuccessfully tried with spring AOP too.

I have the constraints that all exceptions raised to the client are runtimes, and i can't annotate all exceptions with @ApplicationException. (if this annotation were inherited, that would have been a good solution for me)

My spring config looks is :

```
<bean name="/TestService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter" >
   <property name="service" ref="testServiceEJB" />
   <property name="serviceInterface" value="package.shared.services.ITestService" />
</bean> 

<bean name="testServiceEJB" class="package.framework.server.spring.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean" >
    <property name="jndiName" value="framework/TestServiceImpl/local"/>
    <property name="businessInterface" value="package.shared.services.ITestService"/>
</bean>
```

My problem is when starting jboss, it tells me

```
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/TestService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/service-servlet.xml]:

         Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
         Service interface [package.framework.shared.services.ITestService] needs to be implemented by service [package.framework.server.spring.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean@133c8e5] of class [package.framework.server.spring.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean]
```

I don't have this error when using the tag `jee:local-slsb` or declare the bean with class `LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean`.

When debugging, the proxying is not made where it should happened, and a check fails :

```
  at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteExporter.checkServiceInterface(RemoteExporter.java:136)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteExporter.getProxyForService(RemoteExporter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter.prepare(RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter.afterPropertiesSet(RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please clarify further why you are doing this. There might be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed spring's HttpInvokerServiceExporter to unwrap EJBExceptions in handleRequest().